# need to send email with multiple documents attached and properties removed from Document Library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, email

We have one requirement in which we have to send email with mutiple documents attached from document library.

the issue is that we have to remove properties of the documents before sending such emails.

Can anyone suggest some approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make workflow  to initiate email and use below CodePlex project which will help to send list item as attachment

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

Comment: actually we need to remove properties of the document then send email that is most important part in this requirement.